How to extract common properties in MUI Data Grid columns?
I am working on a ReactJS Typescript Application and using MUI as a component library. I need to create a full-featured CRUD Datagrid (like MUI Datagrid component). In the example, most of the columns have some of the same properties. I thought of creating a separate object with the common props needed and apply to all the columns but I keep getting the attached typescript warning/error. What am I doing wrong?
Warning/Error:

Code:
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import DeleteIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlined";
import SaveIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Save";
import CancelIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import {
  GridRowsProp,
  GridRowModesModel,
  GridRowModes,
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridActionsCellItem,
  GridEventListener,
  GridRowId,
  GridRowModel,
  GridRowEditStopReasons,
  GridSlots,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {
  randomCreatedDate,
  randomTraderName,
  randomId,
  randomArrayItem,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

const roles = ["Market", "Finance", "Development"];
const randomRole = () => {
  return randomArrayItem(roles);
};

const initialRows: GridRowsProp = [
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 25,
    joinDate: randomCreatedDate(),
    role: randomRole(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 36,
    joinDate: randomCreatedDate(),
    role: randomRole(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 19,
    joinDate: randomCreatedDate(),
    role: randomRole(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 28,
    joinDate: randomCreatedDate(),
    role: randomRole(),
  },
  {
    id: randomId(),
    name: randomTraderName(),
    age: 23,
    joinDate: randomCreatedDate(),
    role: randomRole(),
  },
];

interface EditToolbarProps {
  setRows: (newRows: (oldRows: GridRowsProp) => GridRowsProp) => void;
  setRowModesModel: (
    newModel: (oldModel: GridRowModesModel) => GridRowModesModel
  ) => void;
}

function EditToolbar(props: EditToolbarProps) {
  const { setRows, setRowModesModel } = props;

  const handleClick = () => {
    const id = randomId();
    setRows((oldRows) => [...oldRows, { id, name: "", age: "", isNew: true }]);
    setRowModesModel((oldModel) => ({
      ...oldModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit, fieldToFocus: "name" },
    }));
  };

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer>
      <Button startIcon={<AddIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
        Add record
      </Button>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}

export default function FullFeaturedCrudGrid() {
  const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(initialRows);
  const [rowModesModel, setRowModesModel] = React.useState<GridRowModesModel>(
    {}
  );

  const handleRowEditStop: GridEventListener<"rowEditStop"> = (
    params,
    event
  ) => {
    if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
      event.defaultMuiPrevented = true;
    }
  };

  const handleEditClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.Edit } });
  };

  const handleSaveClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
  };

  const handleDeleteClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
  };

  const handleCancelClick = (id: GridRowId) => () => {
    setRowModesModel({
      ...rowModesModel,
      [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View, ignoreModifications: true },
    });

    const editedRow = rows.find((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRow!.isNew) {
      setRows(rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));
    }
  };

  const processRowUpdate = (newRow: GridRowModel) => {
    const updatedRow = { ...newRow, isNew: false };
    setRows(rows.map((row) => (row.id === newRow.id ? updatedRow : row)));
    return updatedRow;
  };

  const handleRowModesModelChange = (newRowModesModel: GridRowModesModel) => {
    setRowModesModel(newRowModesModel);
  };

  const commonColumnProps: Partial<GridColDef> = {
    headerAlign: "center",
    align: "center",
    sortable: false,
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
  };

  const columnDefinitions: GridColDef[] = [
    { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 180 },
    {
      field: "age",
      headerName: "Age",
      type: "number",
      width: 80,
    },
    {
      field: "joinDate",
      headerName: "Join date",
      type: "date",
    },
    {
      field: "role",
      headerName: "Department",
      width: 220,
      type: "singleSelect",
      valueOptions: ["Market", "Finance", "Development"],
    },
  ];

  const columns = columnDefinitions.map((columnDef) => {
    const actionsObject = {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      headerName: "Actions",
      width: 100,
      cellClassName: "actions",
      getActions: ({ id }) => {
        const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;

        if (isInEditMode) {
          return [
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<SaveIcon />}
              label="Save"
              sx={{
                color: "primary.main",
              }}
              onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
            />,
            <GridActionsCellItem
              icon={<CancelIcon />}
              label="Cancel"
              className="textPrimary"
              onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
              color="inherit"
            />,
          ];
        }

        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<EditIcon />}
            label="Edit"
            className="textPrimary"
            onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<DeleteIcon />}
            label="Delete"
            onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      },
    };
    return {
      ...commonColumnProps,
      ...columnDef,
      ...actionsObject,
    };
  });

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: 500,
        width: "100%",
        "& .actions": {
          color: "text.secondary",
        },
        "& .textPrimary": {
          color: "text.primary",
        },
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        editMode="row"
        rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
        onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
        processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
        slots={{
          toolbar: EditToolbar as GridSlots["toolbar"],
        }}
        slotProps={{
          toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

Stackblitz:


If you're confident about the structure of your data, a quick fix would be to assert the type of columns. This tells typescript that the objects conform to GridColDef:
   const actionsColumn: GridColDef = {
    field: 'actions',
    type: 'actions',
    headerName: 'Actions',
    width: 100,
    cellClassName: 'actions',
    getActions: ({ id }) => {
      const isInEditMode = rowModesModel[id]?.mode === GridRowModes.Edit;
      if (isInEditMode) {
        return [
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<SaveIcon />}
            label="Save"
            sx={{ color: 'primary.main' }}
            onClick={handleSaveClick(id)}
          />,
          <GridActionsCellItem
            icon={<CancelIcon />}
            label="Cancel"
            onClick={handleCancelClick(id)}
            color="inherit"
          />,
        ];
      }
      return [
        <GridActionsCellItem
          icon={<EditIcon />}
          label="Edit"
          onClick={handleEditClick(id)}
          color="inherit"
        />,
        <GridActionsCellItem
          icon={<DeleteIcon />}
          label="Delete"
          onClick={handleDeleteClick(id)}
          color="inherit"
        />,
      ];
    },
  };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [...columnDefinitions, actionsColumn];


But if you see the output, only the action object is displayed. Can you check the stackblitz app for preview?

@JimParsons hey, I've updated the code to include the actions column separately from the data columns, now it should work as expected
